# How can I make a Panda's mean method work with custom types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a "numeric" class (let's call it `MyType`) for which Panda's `mean` fully works.

My current approach has implemented `MyType` as a subclass of `numbers.Rational`.

```
class MyType(numbers.Rational):
   ...
```

This has allowed Python's `statistics` module to work without any issues.

```
from statistics import mean
result = mean([MyType(1), MyType(2)])
assert isinstance(result, MyType) #passes
```

Unfortunately, similar code in Pandas returns a float instead of an instance of `MyType`.

```
result = pd.Series([MyType(1),MyType(2)]).mean()
assert isinstance(result, MyType) #fails
assert isinstance(result, float) #passes
```

When stepping through Panda's internal code it appears that `MyType` is converted to a float in the `nanmean` method of the `nanops` module ([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2067d7e306ae720d455f356e4da21f282a8a762e/pandas/core/nanops.py#L517)) by the `_ensure_numeric` method on line 563. I haven't been able to find a way to get around this.

What I've tried:

1. `MyType` subclass of `numbers.Real` -- all calculations are correct but the type is wrong
2. `MyType` subclass of `float` -- all the calculations are correct but the type is wrong
3. `MyType` subclass of `ExtensionDtype` -- didn't seem to do anything as far as I could tell

Comment: The `cyberpandas` library has implemented something similar for IP addresses https://github.com/ContinuumIO/cyberpandas/blob/master/cyberpandas/ip_array.py

Comment: @jakub Yeah, I've looked at their library. They're using `ExtensionDtypes` but their IP address isn't a numeric type so they never try to test any of the statistic methods as far as I've een able to tell. None of Panda's out of the box `ExtensionDtypes` are numeric either.